# Combined Cumulative Probabilities of Success

Tags: probability

If you undertake an iterative action 10 times and each time the probability of that action failing is 4% each time, how do you calculate the probability that the outcome of all 10 actions will be successful (meaning, each of the 10 action must succeed)?  The result I am getting is 66.5%

Now, how do you calculate the probability that if this iterative 10-step action were taken twice at the same time by different actors at least ONE of the actors would succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of success of single actor is approximately $0.665$. The probability they both fail the task is approximately $(1-0.665)^2$. The probability at least one will succeed is...

Comment: @CameronBuie Thank you!

Comment: No problem at all. You posted your answer as I was typing up pretty much exactly that, so I opted to fix yours, rather than post mine.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you so very, very much.  Headache subsiding greatly!